# excel vba dynamic cell range getting object error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a dynamic cell range working. I have to Values that tell me the number of rows and columns to use. (I can't use xlToRight, since I don't want all of the values that are in the cells.

So far I tried:

```
Dim xCount As Long
Dim yCount As Long
Dim workRange As Range

xCount = Worksheets("Controls").Range("B4")
yCount = Worksheets("Controls").Range("B5")

workRange = Worksheets("Data").Range(Worksheets("Data").Cells(1,1), Cells(xCount, yCount)
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=workRange
```

Error Message is: Objectvariable or With-blockvariable not assigned (I hope the translation from german is correct :-) The Debugger stops at the "workRange" part.

Could you explain to me, what part of my thinking is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! As BruceWayne suggested I was missing one `Worksheets("Controls")`. But that was not sufficient to remove the error.

I had `set` missing when filling the range into `workRange`. For the sake of having correct code, here is the complete example:

```
Dim xCount As Long
Dim yCount As Long
Dim workRange As Range

With worksheets("Controls")
    xCount = .Range("B4").Value 
    yCount = .Range("B5").Value
End with

With Worksheets("Data")
    set workRange = .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(xCount, yCount))
end with

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=workRange
```

Thanks for the help everyone! :-D

Kaz

Comment: I wonder if `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(xCount, yCount))` would work.  Since you're only using the variable once I think you can apply the range directly without any problem

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, you explicitly gave `workRange` the worksheet for the first cell, you need to do that with the second too.  I like using `with` to help clarify these things:

```
With worksheets("Controls")
xCount = .Range("B4").Value ' I assume this is some number 
yCount = .Range("B5").Value
End with

With Worksheets("Data")
workRange = .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(xCount, yCount))
end with

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=workRange
```

If that doesn't do it, just try `workRange = Worksheets("Data").Range(Worksheets("Data").Cells(1,1), Worksheets("Data").Cells(xCount, yCount)`

Without knowing how you declared `xCount` and `yCount`, if you just did `Dim xCount, yCount` it'll set as Variant (aka anything). Your original declarations will then make Excel think you want a Range (or Cell), not the value of that cell.  If you did `Dim xCount as Integer, yCount as Integer` (or `Long` if you have a large amount of rows), then it'll get that cell's VALUE and use that for your rows in the range.  Otherwise, you'll use `xCount.Row` if you set `xCount` as `Variant` or `Range`.

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: I did as you said and tried with the missing `worksheets` and also tried `with` but both still result in the same error message.

If i just declare `Dim workrange` without any type, the error occurs later (the `ActiveChart` line) and it says `object needed`

So there is something missing in my thinking or in my code.

Comment: I found the answer. I forgot to "set" the workRange. I have put the complete code in another answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understood. You need to assign a value to the selected Range. Try this.

```
 workRange = Worksheets("Data").Range(Worksheets("Data").Cells(1,1), Cells(xCount, yCount).Value = 5
```

This should write a 5 inside the box.

Maybe this helps:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/Ff838238.aspx

---

Ich glaube, du musst dem ganzen noch einen Wert zuweisen.

Setzte ein

```
 .... Cells(xCount, yCount).Value = 5
```

dahinter. Vielleicht funktioniert es dann.

Comment: That won't work.  What that will do is assign the value "FALSE" to the variable `workRange` because `Worksheets("Data").Range(Worksheets("Data").Cells(1,1), Cells(xCount, yCount).Value` does not equal 5